# Construct a JSON Payload in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have to construct a JSON payload that looks like this, can someone help me? I am able to get the straight forward one but unable to build a nested payload. How do I go about adding more nested keys, one inside the other. Also some of the keys and values are dynamic and have to replaced with variables.

```
{
  "format_version": "0.2.19",
  "alliances": {
    "xyz": {
      "environments": {
        "prd": {
          "teams": {
            "abc": {
              "action": "edit",
              "team": "abc",
              "projects": {
                "prjabc": {
                  "project": "prjabc",
                  "cost_center": "0",
                  "custom_iam_policies": [],
                  "iam": {
                    "view_group_email_name": "abc@email.com",
                    "sre_admin_group_email_name": "xyz@email.com"
                  },
                  "allowed_apis": [
                    "api1",
                    "api2"
                  ],
                  "networks": {
                    "network1": {
                      "flags": [
                        "VM"
                      ],
                      "region": "sample-region",
                      "preferred-suffix": "routable"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let say you have an object as such

```
  items = {
    foo: "bar",
    something: "useful"
  }
```

and if you wanted to add other properties or add nested object you can do so like this

```
  subitems = { name: "Johnson" };
  items['subitem'] = subitems;
```

After you've added and finalized the object, you can just use `JSON.stringify(items)` to convert your object into "payload"

Comment: Could you please elaborate? When you say stringify are you saying stringify all the JSON I posted above?
I need to construct it from scratch and make some keys dynamic. Will that be possible using stringify?

Comment: Also if you already have a stringified JSON like the example you posted above, you can load the string into object using `JSON.parse(text)`

Comment: My requirement is slightly more different, so I submit a form and based on the inputs given in the form I have to construct the JSON.
The inputs in the form contain both keys and values. So have to build based on it.
For example:
        var env = current.variables.vpc_environment_type;

 var alliance = current.variables.alliance_business_unit;

 var team = current.variables.alliance_segment_team_name_df_ingestion;

 var project = current.variables.project_name_gcp_df_ingestion_npe;

Those variables declared will store some keys and I have to construct a JSON based on them.

Comment: Then you'll have to loop through the current.variables and set the values accordingly like `var obj={};for(const key in current.variables){obj[key] = current.variables[key];};console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));`